# Why the small cap command is ignored?

Tags: small-caps

I have a thesis front page. Would like to write the surnames with small caps. But it doesn't work. See here (the packages are required):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{url} 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{53pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{53pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{57pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}

{\large \textbf{Albert E\textsc{instein}}}\\[0.2cm]
\end{document}
```

Font sample:
[image]

Used Thesis Template: [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you process your document, you'll see the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined 
using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 10.
```

This warning indicates that small caps in the required series (bold face) are not available in the current (Computer Modern in `OT1` font encoding) font and LaTeX uses a  replacement (Computer Modern in bold face series in `OT1` font encoding).

You need a font having small caps in boldface. This can be achieved using the `T1` encoding (or a package such as `fourier` providing the required font):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{url} 
%\usepackage{fourier} 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{53pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{53pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{57pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}

{\large\textbf{Albert E\textsc{instein}}}\\[0.2cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that small caps and bold face seems redundant.

Also, changes to the page layout are better done using the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

Comment: @gonzalomedian Thank you! :) It works. However, is there a work around? I'm not an expert, and my thesis has another font (see edit above). Somehow, inside the thesis small caps are allowed. But I don't know how to change the title page, since it is generated somehow automatically by the template (means i cannot find the actual page specification -- I'm not an expert)

Comment: @alex Without the actual code used it's imposssible to tell, Edit your question and provide a link to the template used.

Comment: You can typically just include `\scshape` just before the name.  For instance, `\author{\scshape Albert Einstein}`, should change the font to typeset the author name in small caps.

Comment: @cslstr I don't understand your comment. If the font doesn't provide the required combination (small caps+boldface), no matter whether you use the switch `\scshape` or the command `\textsc`, you won't get the desired result.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you much for your help. As you might think it is a pressing moment for me.. I added the thesis link in the question and here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis

Comment: @alex And where exactly do you want to use small caps in the title page?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I agree 100% -- the comment was addressing alex's comment that he "did not know how to change the title page" to use small caps.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. Sorry If I'm causing too much trouble. I accept your answer. It works, if i don't use bold text. Have a nice day. :)